# Ionic Force Whole Apps Render

Tags: android, angularjs, performance, cordova, ionic-framework

Currently I'm developing an apps in Ionic.
However, as the hybrid curse says, I have this big delay when navigating between pages, which only happened after the apps deployed to android device.
After I took a while to investigate about it. Now I know that it is caused by the heavy rendering which Ionic does when we navigate to the other page.

I found that this rendering only happened once at the time we visit that page. The second time we visit, it's already cached so it is faster.

The question is. Anyone knows how to force render all pages in Ionic?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can set `cahce: false` in your ui-router, to states you want `never` to be cached.

```
.state('foo.bar', {
    cache: false;     
    url : '/foo/bar'
    ....

})
```

If you want dont want to cache any state ( which will allow you to rerender each state )

You can set `$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);`

For more references see [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/)

Comment: Unfortunately, my needs will be to force render all page at app start to avoid delay in navigation. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Are you running this on  android ?

Comment: Ionic is slow on android, unless you are running on a very high end android device, and as I can infer, its not that ionic is rendering too much. Its the browser on which ionic is running, which is slow(browser). I suggest you look into `CrossWalk` for Ionic.